# vue3 emit from sub child to top level

Tags: vuejs3, emit

I have installed [vue-cookie-accept-decline](https://github.com/johndatserakis/vue-cookie-accept-decline) a package to show the privacy cookie banner in my App.vue. And now I would like to call some methods from different components of my app.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
  <vue-cookie-accept-decline @reset='reset'....> 
</template>
```

I can refer to my `vue-cookie-accept-decline` template by ref='myPanel1' so I did the following script and I would like to call it by an emit `reset` to restore the banner.

```
setup() {
  const myPanel1 = ref({});

   reset(() => {
      myPanel1.value.removeCookie()
      myPanel1.value.init()
   });

  return {
  myPanel1,
  reset
  }
}
```

This approach is not good for me because I don't know the level of the component calling the emit method. How can I fix it to be able to call the methods anyware?

Comment: This may help: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish based on the description, but I'll try to answer based on the title, *how to emit from a nested child component?*

First, let's cover some

- The vue3 event emitting is tied to the components, so you could use the event bubbling equivalent of prop drilling, but this not a very robust solution.
- Vue3 no longer includes an event bus (like it did in Vue2), so you need to rely on a 3rd party library (like [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt)) for event subscription
- You can use [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) to make a variable available between a parent and any nested component.

If you want to use an `emit` with a deeply nested component, you can pass a mitt instance into the 'provide' context and add the emit listener. Then the child component can use the emitter from the `inject`ed instance to notify of an event.

simple example using `mitt`

```js
// parent
import { provide } from 'vue'
import mitt from 'mitt';

setup() {
  const bus = mitt();
  bus.on('my-event', ()=>{'do stuff'});
  provide('bus', bus);
}
```

```js
// child
import { inject } from 'vue'

setup() {
  const bus = inject('bus');
  bus.emit('my-event', 'optional parameter');
}
```

Comment: Provide/inject was the solution: fast and light! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a simple CDN-based approach and want to use the mitt library for event handling in your Vue.js instances, you can follow these steps:

Include mitt Library
First, include the mitt library via CDN in your HTML file. You can add this before your Vue.js script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mitt@2.1.0/dist/mitt.umd.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3"></script>
```

Initialize mitt Event Emitter
Create a global instance of mitt to serve as an event emitter.

```
<script>
  const emitter = mitt();
</script>
```

Emit and Listen to Events in Vue Instances
In your Vue instances, you can emit events and listen to them using the emitter.

```
<script>
  // Vue instance 1
  const app1 = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        sharedData: 'Initial Data'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateSharedData(newData) {
        this.sharedData = newData;
        emitter.emit('data-updated', newData);
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app1');

  // Vue instance 2
  const app2 = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        sharedData: 'Initial Data'
      }
    },
    created() {
      emitter.on('data-updated', newData => {
        this.sharedData = newData;
      });
    }
  }).mount('#app2');
</script>
```

Integrating with Laravel
Include your JavaScript files in your Laravel Blade template. You can define your Vue instances directly in the Blade template or in separate JavaScript files, depending on your preference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue.js Data Sharing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app1">
        <!-- Vue instance 1 content -->
    </div>

    <div id="app2">
        <!-- Vue instance 2 content -->
    </div>

    <!-- Include JavaScript files -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mitt@2.1.0/dist/mitt.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3"></script>

    <!-- Initialize mitt and Vue instances -->
    <script>
        const emitter = mitt();

        // Vue instances here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

By following these steps, you can use the mitt library for event handling in your Vue.js instances without the need for complex setup or Vue components. This allows you to share data between Vue instances using a simple and lightweight event emitter.